# how can I assign people to rooms with python (google colab)?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

The exam in the method module is about to begin and the participants are divided into three different lecture halls! Let the user enter the first letter of his / her surname and save the result as a variable! If the initial letter is between * A * and * F *, the program should be

You write in the lecture hall 1
output! If the letter is between * G * and * N *, should

You write in the lecture hall 2

be issued. If none of the conditions apply, should

You write in the lecture hall 3
be issued!

Comment: "this" (in the heading) is too abstract. Please try to find the matching words to make this question heading more precise. Thank you.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve the task by yourself? If so, please post your attempt, even if it's not working.

Comment: I assume you get some kind of list of participants as an input, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a little function that takes the string of the name, splits it into the first and last, then extracts the first character of that last name.

Once you have that character, you can use ord() to convert the string to a number set which you can use for logic purposes. Put this in a try catch to not fail when students try to mess with you haha

```
def hall_module(name):
    try:
        first, last = str.split(name)
        letters = [char for char in last]

        check = ord(letters[0].capitalize())

        if ord('A') <= check <= ord('F'):
            print('go to lecture hall 1!')

        elif ord('G') <= check <= ord('N'):
            print('go to lecture hall 2!')

        else:
            print('go to lecture hall 3!')

    except:
        print('please give me a string of your first and last name!')
```

EDIT:

as Taegyung pointed out, letters are already comparable in standard python so you don't need to numerically resolve them:

```
def hall_module(name):
    try:
        first, last = str.split(name)

        letter = last[0].capitalize()

        if 'A' <= letter <= 'F':
            print('go to lecture hall 1!')

        elif 'G' <= letter <= 'N':
            print('go to lecture hall 2!')

        else:
            print('go to lecture hall 3!')

    except:
        print('please give me a string of your first and last name!')
```

Comment: yes! that's exactly what i was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Actually you don't need any of those `ord()`s, because strings are already comparable to each other. Also, you don't need `letters`, because strings are already indexable, so you can do `check = last[0].capitalize()`